# Branch.io: Google App Indexing for links

Tags: android, branch.io, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

I was reading the integration between Branch.io and google app indexing here: https://dev.branch.io/recipes/google_app_indexing/android/

Now, my app is similar to Facebook, its users can make post, comment on posts etc.

Now, not every post gets shared - that's up to the user discretion, however, should every user action (post / comment creation) have an associated branch link attached for app indexing purposes?

It looks like by merely creating my branch link, some sort of indexing takes place - from what I gather from the docs, keywords are indexed but it doesn't look like metadata, title or description are indexed, although the docs were not clear on this.

Lets say I make the post below:

> **Title**: Wow, Star Wars was amazing! **Description**: So, last night the new
>   trailer for Star Wars: The Force Awakens was unleashed upon the world
>   and it was good. Very, very good. But as well as excited fans freaking
>   out over every little detail (did you spot Jakku? Famously the site of
>   the climactic battle between the Rebels and the Empire? Just
>   checking), the Star Wars stars themselves were just as pumped...

In order to maximize the google app index, would it be wise to just use the concatenated title and description as keywords (from the java docs, the method `addKeywords()` doesn't seem to place any restriction on the string used or its length.

```
/**
 * <p>
 * Adds any keywords associated with the content referred
 * </p>
 *
 * @param keywords An {@link ArrayList} of {@link String} values
 * @return This instance to allow for chaining of calls to set methods
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public BranchUniversalObject addKeyWords(ArrayList<String> keywords) {
    this.keywords_.addAll(keywords);
    return this;

}
```

In summary, I have 4 questions:

1. Is it wise to create a branch link each time a user complete an action in my app (post / comment on a post) even though it is not shared so that the content will be indexed?
2. Does anyone know exactly what branch.io will index when you create a link? The docs isn't very clear but it looks like only keywords are indexed.
3. If I do end up concatenating a title and description together as keywords to be indexed, is that the correct way to do app indexing? It feels hacky.
4. Is there anyway to test whether app indexing actually works?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is actually to specify a `title` and `contentDescription` on the `BranchUniversalObject`. Those will definitely be included when Google scrapes.

The easiest way to see what Google sees is to generate a link, then curl that link using the `googlebot` user agent string. For example:

`curl -vvv -A "googlebot" https://bnc.lt/m/your-link-here`

Then you'll see exactly what we serve up to the scraper.

As for testing, there is no good mechanism provided by Google for testing their app indexing product. If you come across one, please post it here.

Lastly, feel free to generate links for content even if those links are not shared. If you do not create links, obviously there is no way for Google to index them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer derrrick. In other words, if I generate links even if the user does not share the link, the title and contentDescription will, in theory, be indexed and be available in google searches?

Comment: That's correct. Definitely try running the curl from the command line if you're curious as to what data has made it onto the page. Also, feel free to shoot us an email via support <at> branch.io with one of your generated links if you have questions about it.

Comment: Thanks - i sent you an email now with my link and my question on it.